# please help me in using inheritance of object

Tags: c#

I tried using inheritance in all my object class. below are my example

```
public class Member : Order
{
   private string _employeeId;
   private string _employeeName;

   public string EmployeeId
   {
       get { return _employeeId; }
       set { _employeeId = value; }
   }

   public string EmployeeName
   {
       get { return _employeeName; }
       set { _employeeName = value; }
   }

}


public class Order
{
    private int _id;
   private string _itemName;

   public string ID
   {
       get { return _id; }
       set { _id = value; }
   }

   public string ItemName
   {
       get { return _itemName; }
       set { _itemName= value; }
   }

}
```

Comment: @Abel - How does it seem correct? Syntactically, maybe. But I can't envisage any scenario in which a member is also an order!

Comment: @Greg: sorry, I deleted my comment after I found that it was only syntactically correct. Member is an Order seems a bit too odd (unless a member is something you can order, envisage that!) ;-)

Comment: some friendly advice: to have your question reopened and better answered, change your question into an actual question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inheritance makes  an "IS A" relation between classes.

It is highly unlikely that **"a Member is an Order"**, so you're not using it correctly.

Without further information it's hard to give you better advice.

A more plausible model would be :

- An Employee **is** a Person
- A Member **is** an Employee (doubt here)
- A Member **has** 0 or more  Orders

---

```
class Person { }
class Employee: Person { }
class Member : Employee
{
    public IList<Order> Orders { get; private set; }
}

class Order
{
   public int MemberId { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: everyone please be advice on how to use a chain object like the sample in above

Comment: You seem to need a basic introduction to inheritance, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29  and http://studweb.north.londonmet.ac.uk/~chalkp/proj/ootutor/inheritance.html

Comment: Hi, I use this for automatic properties.

If you have any technique using automatic properties please let me know. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using C#, you could shorten your example by using automatic properties:

```
public class Order
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}

public class Member : Order
{
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
}
```

Now, is the problem that you want to use the same Name and Id properties on Order and Member? Then you would do this instead:

```
public class Order
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Member : Order
{
}
```

But, could you give more detail about what you want these two classes to be used for? Why does a Member inherit from Order?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that looks fine. I can't say if it makes sense to use inheritance that way for those specific classes, but if that is what you want, you did it correctly.

In C# version 3 and later you can use shorthand to create properties:

```
public class Member : Order  { 

  public string EmployeeId { get; set; } 
  public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

} 

public class Order { 

   public string ID { get; set; }
   public string ItemName { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: I mean.how to use a chain object in business logic

Comment: everyone please be advice on how to use a chain object like the sample in above.